# C# phone number check

Tags: c#, regex

I am doing validation for 10 digit North American phone numbers (coding below). I am accepting digits only. What I can't seem to figure out is how to alter this so that if the number entered begins with 911, 411 or a 0, an error is thrown.

```
string phoneNum = phoneTextBox.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{10}$");
Match match = regex.Match(phoneNum);
if (!match.Success)
{
   MessageBox.Show(phoneNum + " is not a valid 10 digit phone number (Ex. 6134561234)");
}
```

Comment: You should use another regex for that validation.  check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?!411|911|0)\d{10}$");
                           +++++++++++++
```

They're called **negative lookahead assertions**.

Comment: thanks! I've done alot of googling but never came across that

Answer (score 1):

You can use more advance patterns.  Try to find the one here - http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

I've tried running Regex Tracer and it finds ok number 4111111111 for patter - ^\d{10}$.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative - a phone number parser:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31998/Advanced-Phone-Number-Type-Implementation